# how to register or save the user that is sent from ios app in rails server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am using devise authentication in rails server and now i have a requirement where the ios app will login to `facebook` and get the access token and the user information and i am little confused on what data they will send to the server and how i need to save the user. Do i have to use a seperate logic for handling this. I am not much familiar with this and please tell me  what should they send to server and how i should save the user. In case of email sign up they will send email and password and i can register the user but how about this? as they might not send me a password or password confirmation.

please help me.

Answer (score 0):

On the iOS client you can login to facebook and you will get a facebook_access_token.  So you just need to pass the facebook_access_token to the server.

On you server side you can use the facebook_access_token and you can get the required profile details along with facebook UID from facebook based on their privacy settings.

So you need to have a separate logic to use the facebook_access_token and get the **required profile details and UID** and register the user with these details and don't forget to store the UID on your user table.

you can try [omniauth_facebook](http://railscasts.com/episodes/360-facebook-authentication).  If you are using devise then you can combine devise and onmiauth also refer [this blog](http://www.supriyasurve.com/2012/06/rails-3-devise-omniauth-facebook.html).

Comment: ok i can understand but could you please explain me a bit more on that special logic. Actually there will be user model and it will require the password and some other fields so how could i save those things without having a password. Or i read, in twitter the email cannot be accessed so how about storing the email for that user?

Comment: you can get the profile email so email should not be a problem.  But for password either you can have some default password or you can validate the password presence only if uid is not present. And if you are using devise for authentication then you can try devise and omniauth.

Comment: Ok and one more thing, if for a change the iphone app itself gets the token and gets the user information and why not it should send those details. If this is the scenario, then how can i handle? And coming to the one like you said, if i use omniauth then how will the user call for sign up and what parameters will they be sending and how will they login after registration?

Comment: Go with Devise and Omniauth together so devise will take care of normal registration, forget password, update password, remember password etc and onniauth_facebook will take care of your facebook login.